# Can only specific SQL users be forced to use TLS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, encryption

My school would like to develop custom software for some embedded devices. As part of this, we may need the devices to connect to an SQL Server instance.

Is it possible to force specific SQL users to use encryption when connecting to the server? We don't want to force it for the entire instance because of some important legacy software.

We're also evaluating other (frankly, better) solutions, but I want to know what's possible.

Comment: As far as I remember encryption protocol is established before sending the logon credentials and it is a server wide setting.

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't force specific clients to encrypt.  You could configure all of the specified clients to encrypt, though.

Comment: A client can *request" the session to be encrypted, though an attribute in the connection string. But that isn't the same as enforcing a client login's traffic to be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for forcing encryption from the server side is either all or nothing.  There is no way on the server side to configure it so that it only forces certain logins or connections to encrypt.

Clients, however, can be configured to either encrypt the connection or not.  For example, adding [`encrypt=true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-2017) to a Microsoft JDBC connection string, or [`SSL=require`](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html)   to a jTDS connection string will configure that client connection to be encrypted.  If you're using an ODBC DSN, the configuration typically has an option for encryption as well.  You should be able to quickly learn how to configure a given SQL client for encryption by doing a bit of searching on the Internet.

One note of caution is that you may need to update SQL Server and the SQL client that is being used if you are forcing TLS 1.2 (see [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)).  The latest release of the jTDS driver has a defect that causes it to fail with TLS 1.2, but there is a developer build available in the forums with a fix.  The last official release of jTDS was in 2013, so you'll have to use an unreleased build if you'll be forcing TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Tony Hinkle's answer is spot on.  It's an all or nothing situation for encryption.

If you really require this sort of setup, my suggestion would be to create a new instance (either a new named-instance on the local server itself or a new instance on a separate server) which [forces all connections be encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

This new instance can then either connect to the current instance via one of the following approaches

- [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

  - If your volume isn't too significant
- [Replicated Database (Transactional Replication)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017)

  - If volume is more significant AND the database tables in question [satisfy replication requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/frequently-asked-questions-for-replication-administrators?view=sql-server-2017#how-do-i-manage-constraints-on-published-tables)
- [Read-Only Replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)

  - If your application only needs read-only access

Depending on application requirements, one of these approaches may do exactly what you need.  I know it's not exactly what you're hoping for, but there are solutions that adhere to your requirements if you are unable to change them.